# Bluebird promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

I am a beginner in JS and want to send sequential requests in Node.js.
I am trying to do it using Promises (Bluebird). I am using supertest library to send the request. When I execute function call(), debug() is executed before sendRequest(), but I would like the debug run after sendRequest has resolved. How to achieve this?

```
var call = function() {
  getConfig
    .then(function(config) {
      sendRequest(config);
    })
    .then(function(result) {
      debug('Result', result);
    });
}

var getConfig = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  var config = injector.get('config');
  config.property = newProperty;
  if (config) {
    resolve(config);
  } else {
    reject('Config is ', config);
  }
});

var sendRequest = function(configFile) {
  var config = configFile;
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    request(server)
      .get(endpoint)
      .expect(200)
      .end(function(err, res) {
        if (err) {
          reject(err);
        }

        resolve(res.body);
      });
  })
};
```

How to chain several of these getConfig and sendRequest calls together, so that they start after previous operation has finished?

```
var result1;
var result2;
var call = function () {
  getOldConfig
    .then(function (config) {
        return sendRequest(config);
    })
    .then(function (result) {
        result1 = result;
    })
    .then(getActualConfig)
    .then(function (config) {
        return sendRequest(config);
    })
    .then(function (result) {
        result2 = result;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to return inner Promise

```
getConfig
    .then(function (config) {
        return sendRequest(config); // NB
    })
    .then(function (result) {
        debug('Result', result);
    });
```